# Selecting one row value based on anothers row value

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Hi, guys

Can't find answer in other topics, so asking here.

I have a Table in database

```
Table
------------------------------
id | name    | last_name   | created_by_id                    |

 1 | Bilbo ..| Baggins.....|    0  ....................       |

 2 | Frodo . | Baggins.....|    1  ...................        |
```

Is there any way i can get 1st row name value by using 2nd row `created_by_id` ?

I need to get sentence **Frodo Baggins was created by Bilbo Baggins**.

Can't find the right sql sentence

Comment: What is `created_by_id` a reference to? `id`? In your example, there is nobody with `id = 0`

Comment: Its just ant example. Need to get value of first row by using seconds row creted_by_id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `self` join :

```
select t.*, t1.name, t1.last_name 
from table t inner join
     table t1 
     on t1.id = t.created_by_id
where t.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a join

```
select *,<your string stuff here>
from <table> as a
    inner join <table> as b
        on a.id = b.created_by_id
```